# Python Discord bot fails to log links and images

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to log only site-links and image-links posted (whilst ignoring chat or banter) to one of my Discord servers and created a simple Python Discord bot to do this. It successfully saves a lot of the site-links and image-links to file. However a lot of other links, particularly ones which were posted 'en masse' by users (i.e. attached multiple images or links to a single message) failed to be logged.

Here's my simple bot:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os

#Initializes the bot to accept commands.
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:   #This prevents a self-propogating echo chamber of text!

        if(message.content == "log_channel"):
            async for message in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=5000000, reverse=True):
                with open(os.getcwd()+"/logs.txt", "a") as output_file: 
                    if("http" in message.content): output_file.write(message.content+"\n")

client.run(xxx-xxx-xxx)
```

What could I do to ensure even those messages that contain multiple images and links get logged accurately?

Comment: It looks like you are looking for only links and such with message in content "http"
but what about links with https? Add more checks for messages posted in your discord room to catch all other message.content

Comment: What exactly is it that you're interested in capturing?  I would recommend looking at the contents of `message.embeds` and `message.attachments` especially.

Comment: Happy new year! My aim is to basically extract any kind of links from the messages. Problem is, the bot does not extract from messages that have multiple links or pics. Would you be able to suggest code that is more ‘rigorous’ in extracting links?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to check if the message is an embed or a link and then log it and check if the message is anything else then embed or link ignore it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).